# How to verify signature while downloading log4j?

Tags: pgp, digital-signature

From the [log4j download page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html).

> The PGP signatures can be verified using PGP or GPG. First download the KEYS as well as the asc signature file for the relevant distribution. Make sure you get these files from the main distribution directory, rather than from a mirror. Then verify the signatures using
>
> % gpg --import KEYS
>
> % gpg --verify log4j-1.2.17.tar.gz.asc

My questions are:

1. Which portion of 'KEYS' webpage do I need to download ? Should `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` and `----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` be included in the key signed by Christian Grobmeier ?
2. What does KEYs in `gpg --import KEYS` mean? Is 'KEYS' a file on the local desktop? If yes which format? txt?

Comment: There's a maven plugin to verify signatures: http://www.simplify4u.org/pgpverify-maven-plugin/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the second question, the KEYS is the file that is linked on the apache site. You just have to download it as is (and by as is I mean, with all the comments and the --BEGIN --END shenanigans). Just right click the link and save it like this.

To the second question, the `gpg --import` command will sort out what is a key and what is not, importing all the keys in bulk.

Comment: interesting, thanks a ton. What format should KEYS be in ?